# very odd "Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')" error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, frontend, google-chrome-devtools

I am making a website that takes data from a given url, displays it to my front end, then does some functionality with that data (not implemented yet). The error i'm facing right now is when i go to load up localHost:3000, my website runs normally. If i open my browsers built in dev tools (google chrome) and refresh the website, i get a "Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')" error. Ive tried brainstorming why this is happening but Im at a crossroads.

```
import Head from "next/head";
import styles from "@/styles/Home.module.css";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";

import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });
let foundationUrl = "https://api.binance.us/api/v3/ticker/price?symbol=";

function createPriceFed(foundationUrl, ticker1, ticker2) {
  var url = foundationUrl + ticker1 + ticker2;
  return url;
}

async function btcPriceFeed() {
  var url = createPriceFed(foundationUrl, "BTC", "USD");
  let response = await fetch(url);
  if (response.ok) {
    let json = await response.json();
    let priceData = json["symbol"] + " : " + json["price"];
    if (
      typeof document != "undefined" &&
      typeof document != "[object Object]"
    ) {
      let priceContainer = document.querySelector("#btc");
      priceContainer.innerHTML = priceData;
    }
  } else {
    alert("HTTP-Error " + response.text);
  }
  setTimeout(btcPriceFeed, 5000);
}

async function ethPriceFeed() {
  var url = createPriceFed(foundationUrl, "ETH", "USD");
  let response = await fetch(url);
  if (response.ok) {
    let json = await response.json();
    let priceData = json["symbol"] + " : " + json["price"];
    if (
      typeof document != "undefined" &&
      typeof document != "[object Object]"
    ) {
      let priceContainer = document.querySelector("#eth");
      priceContainer.innerHTML = priceData;
    }
  } else {
    alert("HTTP-Error " + response.text);
  }
  setTimeout(ethPriceFeed, 5000);
}

async function lrcPriceFeed() {
  var url = createPriceFed(foundationUrl, "LRC", "USDT");
  let response = await fetch(url);
  if (response.ok) {
    let json = await response.json();
    let priceData = json["symbol"] + " : " + json["price"];
    if (
      typeof document != "undefined" &&
      typeof document != "[object Object]"
    ) {
      let priceContainer = document.querySelector("#lrc");
      priceContainer.innerHTML = priceData;
    }
  } else {
    alert("HTTP-Error " + response.text);
  }
  setTimeout(lrcPriceFeed, 5000);
}

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <div id="btc" className="btc"></div>
      <div id="eth"></div>
      <div id="lrc"></div>
      
    </>
  );
};

export default dynamic(() => Promise.resolve(Home), { ssr: false });

btcPriceFeed();
ethPriceFeed();
lrcPriceFeed();
```

[opening website without dev tools open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UxfJ.png)

[opening website with dev tools open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9O6q3.png)

I tried refactoring my code and reviewing areas where expect this error would occur from, but i have yet to get rid of the error.

Comment: The error means that `priceContainer` is `null`, which would happen when there is no element on the page with id "btc" or "eth" or whichever one is relevant.

Comment: This is why you generally shouldn't mix React with vanilla JS DOM manipulation. The code is likely trying to select the element before it's been rendered, and throwing an error because it doesn't exist yet. I'd recommend moving all of your API calls inside your React components.

Answer (score 0):

The error means that `priceContainer` is `null`. It happens because that piece of code executes before the return of `Home()`, so the `#btc` don't exist in the HTML page yet.